# Model for comparison of two subsets of the same data

Tags: categorical-data, model-selection, discrete-data

I am looking to perform an analysis on a subset of the data and compare it to a larger subset.

My data is primarily categorical and the dependent variable is binary.

I want to compare

$y^*= \beta X$

with

$y^{**}= \beta X$

where $y^*$ and $y^{**}$ are from two, non overlapping subsets of the same dataset and independent variables.

At this stage, due to the structure of the data I am leaning towards a random or fixed effect probit for my model.

My hypothesis would be $\beta^*-\beta^{**}$=0
the $\beta$ coefficients are the key interest here. I want to analyse the difference between the coefficients in both models.

I think one way I could do it would be to just specify identical models with a probit or a logit and just run the and then do significance tests on the coefficients to see if they are different.

I would prefer it if there was a way I could nest estimates of coefficients for both $y^*$ and $y^{**}$ within the same model. My best guess at the moment is the BVP but I am not convinced that is the best choice because typically they are used to estimate different dependent variables.

Comment: Using a bivariate probit model assumes that you have two correlated binary outcomes using the same data. Here you want to compare the same outcome using different subsets of the data. I suppose that bi-variate probit regression might work.

Comment: As @missingdataguy said, you would use bi-variate probit if you were trying to predict two dependent binary variables. Here it sounds more like you have one variable to predict, but two datasets. What do you expect to find from your analysis?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are looking for in your analysis, but is there any reason you can't simply use a categorical variable as a predictor that acts as an indicator of inclusion or exclusion from the specified subsets? It seems a more straightforward way of comparing the two then running separate models. e.g. Y=BX+aZ where Z=0 for one subset and Z=1 for the other subset. This is assuming that the model specified by BX is the same for both subsets.

Comment: @RyanSimmons, I thought of something like that. What I am most interested in is the impact different parts of the sample have on the $\beta$ coefficients. I have edited the question slightly, you are right. Bivariate probit isn't quite the right tool. To make it clearer, my dependent variable is employment and I want to observe the differences in experience of migrants vs non migrants.

Comment: what you do typically is you add the p (p is the rank of your design matrix) n-vector of dummies I_i=I(i\in**), run the model with the $p$ dummies  an wald-test for the null that all dummies are jointly 0. If the number of rows of Y** is too small to estimate those dummies, you can fit a ridge logistic model with many values of lambda and use an CV criterion to see if  lambda^* is close to 0.

Comment: @user603 Could you please elaborate on that. I don't quite follow.

Comment: OK; what are the dimensions of your object (number of rows and columns of X, and number of rows y* and y**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to perform a dummy variable regression; however, the trick is with the dummy variable interacting with *every* known slope. This is the equivalent to run two or more separate regressions, one on sample 1, one on sample two etc.; however, you keep everything within one model.

In the case you have two samples, you have:

$y =  \beta X + D_1 + D_1 X +u$

where $\beta$ is a vector holding $1,\beta_1,...,\beta_n$.

with $D_1=1$ an indicator for belonging to a particular sample, e.g. immigrant status.

Note this is equivalent to the non-matrix form, e.g. with two covariates:

$y = \alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 +  D_1 + D_1 \beta_1 x_1 + D_1 \beta_2 x_2  + u$

To test your hypothesis, you can use the delta method for non-linear combinations of estimators. This is standard in some packages (nlcom for STATA), or you can calculate the test statistics yourself, which is a $\chi^2(p)$ distribution and the sandwich matrix binding the derivatives of the above expression on both sides. This is handy for more than one dummy.

However, here with just one dummy variable, in effect, what you want to test.

($ D_1 \beta_1= 0, D_1 \beta_2 =0)$

which can be simplified to use the joint hypothesis $D_1=0, \beta_1\ne0, \beta_2\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the question was to simply add in a dummy variable. It has the disadvantage that it doesn't show information about the relationships with all the coefficients. Another solution would be to add an interaction with all the variables of interests and a dummy variable distinguishing the two subsets.